# EPSON POS printer TM-T70E setting character set ( iOS SDK )

Tags: ios, character, point-of-sale, thermal-printer

I have an EPSON TM-T70E (Ethernet) pos printer. I'm using the ios SDK and I can print everything ok. But I want to be able to print Greek Characters. So I must change the character set the printer is using. In the iOS SDK I can't find any way to change the character set. So I was thinking about sending direct ESC/POS command to make the change. The problem is that documentation is very poor and I can't find a way to send direct ESC/POS commands to the ethernet version of the printer. Can someone please provide some directions?

Comment: If you open a socket to the ip address, port 9100 (typical default), you can send direct esc/pos. is this what you are asking for?

Comment: I guess so. The command I want to send is: ESC T 17  ( I think this is the character set for greek ). Can you please help on how to do this?

Comment: This post shows bones of it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578355/printing-directly-to-a-thermal-printer-using-esc-pos-commands-executed-in-c-shar?rq=1

Comment: I can send the esc command as string? Do I put spaces or not?